# SQL: Select a partition group which dies not have a specified value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table as follows

| IDNumber | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Apple |
| 123 | Mango |
| 123 | Banana |
| 126 | Apple |
| 126 | Mango |
| 126 | Orange |
| 128 | Apple |
| 128 | Mango |
| 128 | Banana |
| 151 | Apple |
| 151 | Mango |
| 151 | Banana |

I have used the partition by clause to partition the group based on ID Number.

```
with part as (Select IDNumber,count(IDNumber) over(Partition by IDNumber) cnt  from myTable) 
Select IDNumber from myTable where do not exists ???"Orange in partitionGroup"????
```

Problem:I am not really sure how this can be achieved.For a given ID, i would need a partition group to NOT select if a given value is present.

This gives me a partition where every group has three Names, But i do not want the IDNumber to be sselected if it has Orange as Name.
Please let me know in case any other details are required. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain *clearly* the logic you want to implement.  Edit your question and show the results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT IDNumber
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY IDNumber
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Another way:

```sql
SELECT IDNumber
FROM yourTable
WHERE IDNumber NOT IN (
    SELECT IDNumber FROM yourTable WHERE Name = 'Orange'
);
```

Comment: Hey Tim, This seems to be  a nice approach. I guess this should effectively remove the group which has Orange. Thanks very much. Appreciate your help. :) I am trying it now.

Comment: Thanks tested in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bc0c3/1 and works great.

Answer (score 0):

> But i do not want the IDNumber to be selected if it has Orange as Name.

You can use `not exists` for this:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from myTable t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.name = 'Orange'
                 );
```

You can also phrase this using window functions, but that seems unnecessary.